# SQL Pivot syntax on several fields including null value

Tags: sql, null, pivot

I have (for me) complex situation where I need to use pivot.
Setup is like this:

```
Parent
    Id
    Filter1
    Filter2
    TypeId

FirstChild
    Id
    ParentId
    Value
    Count
    ValidFrom
    ValidTo

SecondChild
    Id
    FirstChildId
    Value

TypeTable
    Id
    Type
```

In data, Filter1, Filter2 and Type from Parent create unique set (we have Index on DB to make sure it stays that way). On FirstChild we have in code validation so that there is no overlaping on ValidFrom - ValidTo ranges - if you execute query for a date, you get one row per parent
For ease, Type field in Parent can contain Type1, Type2, Type3 (there are 75 types in total, but that part of query would be generated dynamicaly)
Furthermore, Value can be null for some Type or the row might not exist at all and needs to be returned as null in that case.
SecondChild should be returned as first row that belongs to the FirstChild

So, query that is returning not pivoted dataset looks like this

```
Select p.Id As ParentId, t.Type, c1.Value As Value, c1.Count, c2.Value As AdditionalValue
From TypeTable as t
Left Join Parent as p On t.Id = p.TypeId And Filter1 In @listFilter1 And Filter2 In @listFilter2
Left Join FirstChild As c1 On (c1.ValidFrom <= @ValidOn And c1.ValidTo >= @ValidOn) And c1.ParentId = p.Id
Left Join (Select * From SecondChild Where Id In (Select Min(Id) From SecondChild Group By FirstChildId)) As c2 On c2.FirstChildId = c1.Id
Where t.Id In(List of Id)
```

Given the search filters, all 3 fields (value, count and additionalValue) can be null.
But, per Type, there can be only one row.

What I need is to Pivot the result into:

```
ParentId | Type1Value | Type1Count | Type1AdditionalValue | Type2Value | Type2Count | Type2AdditionalValue | and so on for 75 types
```

Currently, I can get Value pivoted per Type, but only using aggregation Sum(Value), where I loose null (and I need that)
For attempt of Pivot on 3 fields, I have used 3 separate Pivot statements and Join each of them on top. But that is very complex (and in the end I need 7 fields pivoted).
So, push me in the right direction for a way to simplify my query.

Comment: 75 types -- so you want a result with ~225 columns per row? I'd see if some time can't be invested in having client code that doesn't require such an atrocious pivot but can just read the results as rows. A little code there can go a long way to not having to code horrific things in SQL.

Comment: I'd apreciate constructive comments only. 
As I do not have time nor the place to explain entire business logic here, let's keep to the mather at hand.
And, there will never be all 75 types, there can be quite a few of them and thus the part with dynamic biulding of that part query...

Comment: A simple "that approach won't work for me" is enough, at least that gives me the benefit of the doubt that my comment was *intended* to be constructive (which it was). You'd be surprised how often people ignore approaches that are available to them but not taken because they were never even considered (out of convenience or culture). My personal preference is to stay far away from dynamic pivots in SQL, so you have my sympathies, even if I don't want to work on this. :P

Comment: It's not a mather of approach, it's tha matter of requested (and accepted) data format for the outpuut. That part can't be changes.

Comment: Btw, your DBMS and its version is not specified, since pivoting logic might differ due to those factors.